# react append child

Tags: reactjs, appendchild, createelement

I'm trying to understand why my code keeps failing, I have 3 inputs which I'm trying to make appear as the item in a TODO list with React. The error say "appendChild is not a function".

I've seen this same code working on plain old JS, and I'm trying to use it on React.

I'm really new to JS and React, so please explain any possible reply as basic as you can.

```
    const cargarDatos = (pool) => {
    pool.preventDefault()

    const valueList = datos.text + ' ' + datos.amount + ' ' + datos.date
    const list = List.document.getElementsByClassName('.div-list')

    const itemList = document.createElement("div")
    console.log(valueList)
    itemList.innerText = valueList
    itemList.classList.add('item-List')
    list.appendChild(itemList)
}
```

List JSX component

```
import React from "react";

export function List () {

return (
    <>
        <h2>List</h2>
        <div className={'div-list'}></div>
    </>
)
}
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: When using react you can use react states and map them to a component, when you add a new item to the state the component will add automatically with react. This is the whole point of using react.

Comment: Your `list` variable is `undefined` because of dot in class name. const list = List.document.getElementsByClassName(' `.`div-list '). Remove it and your code will work. But as Abdullah say it`s not the best way how to use react

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help, but since im new to React I dont have a complete idea about how to use States, im pretty sure Im currently making a LOT of funny mistakes, I dont know any better than this.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementsByClassName` function always returns an array that is why your code isn't working.

If you know there is only one element with the class `div-list` you can fix it by selecting the first element in the array.

```js
const list = List.document.getElementsByClassName('.div-list')[0];
```

Comment: Yes, div-list is in fact a Parent div to wich I need to append child div-items to create the TODO list.

Comment: So did it work? if so please accept my answer so future visitors will know this is a correct solution.

Comment: Sadly, no. It would not append a child element to the parent div.